# How to handler <tr> event click to get attr and run some function

Tags: jquery, json

i have problem with my table that generate from function.

i need to get the clicked td attr and run some function. 
but it doesn't work.
what wrong with my code..?

generate_table.js

```
function generate_table(data,lnk){
    tbl='';
    table_stayle=' border=1; cellpadding=0; cellspacing=0;' ;
    th_stayle='style="color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bolder; background-color:#003366" ';
    tr_stayle=' bgcolor="#CCCCFF" ';
    td_stayle='';
    tr_alternate='';
        var tbl_body = '';
        var tbl_h = '';
            $.each(data[0], function(k , v) {
                tbl_h=tbl_h + "<td>"+k+"</td>";
                })
        tbl_h ='<tr align="center" '+th_stayle+'>'+tbl_h+ '</tr>';
            //detail
        var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            var row_key='';
                $.each(this, function(k , v) {
                    if(k==lnk){
                        row_key=v;
                        tbl_row =tbl_row + "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'>"+v+"</a></td>";//<a href='"+v+"'>
                    }else{
                        tbl_row =tbl_row + "<td>"+v+"</td>";
                    }
                })
            tbl_body =tbl_body+ '<tr '+tr_stayle+' kode="'+row_key+'" class="tbl_tr" >'+tbl_row + '</tr>';               
        })
        return '<table id="tabel" '+table_stayle+'>'+tbl_h+tbl_body+'</table>';
}
```

php code like this :

```
    <script language="javascript1.5" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.5" src="generate_tabel.js"></script>
<style>
#div_body {overflow:auto; height:300px;}
</style>
======================================================================<br />
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="load data">
<div id="div_body" style="overflow:auto;border:solid; border-width:medium; width:400;300">    
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        url="getjson.php";
        aa=$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    //JSON DATA LIKE THIS:
    //          aa='[{"Id":"1","wh2":"HandPhone","wh3":"-"},
    //          {"Id":"2","wh2":"Acessory","wh3":"-"},
    //          {"Id":"3","wh2":"Batery","wh3":"-"},
    //          {"Id":"4","wh2":"Chassing","wh3":"-"}]';
            $('#div_body').html(generate_table(data,"wh2"));
            });
        });

    //  $(".tbl_row").click(function(){
    //        alert($("tr").attr("kode"));
    //        //some function
    //     });
    $('#div_body').on('click','.tbl_tr',function(){ alert($(this).attr("kode")); });
});
</script>
```

and the function handler click :

```
$(".tbl_tr").click(function(){
          alert($("tr").attr("kode"));
          //some function
       });
```

yes.. mention the answer i change the jquery :

```
<script language="javascript1.5" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.5" src="generate_tabel.js"></script>
```

and

```
   $(".tbl_tr").on("click", function(){
      alert($(this).attr("kode"));
      //some function
    });
```

in Firefox error console no give message. but the alert doesnt run.

here my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/candrapurnama/DcBwA/)

solved:
i wrote simple code for simulation.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
======================================================================<br />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK">
<div id="aaa"><a href=""><span >aaaaaaa</span></a>
</div>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#aaa').html(' <table id="tbl" border=1><tr code="k1" class="ss"><td><a>aaa</a></td></tr><tr code="k2" class="ss"><td><a>bb</a></td></tr><tr code="k3" class="ss"><td><a>cc</a></td></tr></table>');
});
$('#aaa').on('click','#tbl tr a',function(a){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('code'));
});
</script>
```

thank you all. I love you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dynamically creating the table.  You need to delegate.  Since it looks like you are creating the table inside of the `#div_body` element, it would probably be the most efficient parent element to use.  The element must exist in the dom when working with the element

By using delegation the `.tbl_tr` click event will bubble up to the `#div_body` and that is where the event will be handled.  By doing that it also reduces the amount of event handlers attached since by binding you would have attached one for every `.tbl_tr` element, now you just have one handling the events

If using jQuery 1.7+ use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#div_body').on('click','.tbl_tr',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("kode"));
});
```

or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if below 1.7

```
$('#div_body').delegate('.tbl_tr','click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("kode"));
});
```

Use above for dynamically created elements

---

The two styles below are eventually the same thing

```
$(".tbl_tr").on("click", function(){
      alert($(this).attr("kode"));
      //some function
});
$(".tbl_tr").click(function() {
      alert($(this).attr("kode"));
      //some function
});
```

Use only when you know the element will be there when dom is loaded or you are attaching after the element has been added to the dom

Comment: Are you using the one of the first two examples I showed?  Don't use the bottom two

Comment: `$('#div_body').on('click','.tbl_tr',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("kode"));
});`    <-- use that

Comment: Do you notice the difference between what you're using and what I'm asking you to use?

Comment: i hace change angain in php file with $('#div_body').on('click','.tbl_tr',function(){ alert($(this).attr("kode")); }); that code run with selector $('#div_body'). no change result. may i send the complete code to you?

Comment: Do you have a website url?  or maybe make a jsfiddle? also why is that inside your .php file?  shouldn't it be in your .js file?

Comment: i dont have website and jsfiddle. if you whise i will send via mail or share google drive. i have edit PHP file in the question. and JS as it all. and in the getjson.php, result : [{"Id":"1","wh2":"HandPhone","wh3":"-"},{"Id":"2","wh2":"Acessory","wh3":"-"},{"Id":"3","wh2":"Batery","wh3":"-"},{"Id":"4","wh2":"Chassing","wh3":"-"}]

Comment: Is that the response you see inside your browser?  Also I don't know PHP so I wouldn't be able to read/work with your server side code

Comment: in Firefox error console no give message. but the alert doesnt run. i will create account in jsfiddle.

Comment: @CandraPurnama do you think it's because you spelled `table` wrong  <script language="javascript1.5" src="generate_tabel.js"></script>

Comment: i think is not. because table was out in page, but TR event not work. see my jsfiddle in question.

Comment: Can you try remove the `language` part off the script?  maybe that's affecting it

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are "drawing" the Table after assign the click event to ".tbl_tr".

Try writing like this:

```
$(".tbl_tr").on("click", function(){
          alert($(this).attr("kode"));
          //some function
});
```

Comment: I am sorry. this code returned error message $(".tbl_tr").on is not a function.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? must be below 1.7

Comment: "Listen" to what @wirey is saying on the next answer

Comment: <script language="javascript1.5" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.5" src="generate_tabel.js"></script>

Comment: i dont know why it is happen. is it because $(".tbl_tr").on("click", fu... location is in the outside of generate_table.js?